# Find cached files of unpacked aar files in gradle script

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android project where a library is included (aar). Gradle will unpack and store the files in the gradle cache (.gradle\caches\transforms-2). I need a gradle script where I can retrieve a file from this cache and move it into my project. Does anybody know how this can be done?

The moving part is working. I just need to get the correct path

```
tasks.register('moveFile', Copy) {
  from "${path_to_build_cache}/path/to/folder/file.conf"
  into "${project.rootDir.path}/path/to/folder/"
}
```

**EDIT**

I have now tried the solution posted by @tim_yates. The problem is that I am now receiving the error `CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method from() for arguments [ZIP 'C:\Users\nthemmer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\path\to\aar on task ':my-project:movefiles' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask` It seems that the aar file is read correctly but it has not only one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of searching the cache, you should be able to use Gradle to find it for you...

Here's an example:

```
configurations {
    aar
}

dependencies {
    aar('com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.3.0@aar')
}

tasks.register('moveFile', Copy) {
    from(zipTree(configurations.aar.singleFile)) {
        include "res/values/values.xml"
    }
    into project.layout.buildDirectory.dir('here')
}
```

That copies the file into `./build/here/res/values/values.xml`

#### Edit

So there's probably multiple ways of doing this, but here's one.

Define a configuration that we will use for the single dependency you want a file from, and make `compileClasspath` extend from it (so the dependency ends up back in the compile classpath where it was previously)

```
configurations {
    aar
    compileClasspath.extendsFrom aar
}
```

Then in the dependencies where you reference the aar, you should be able to use `aar` instead of `compileClasspath`

```
dependencies {
    aar('com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.3.0@aar')
}
```

Then you can use the `moveFile` task from above, and there will just be a single file

Not 100% sure what you have currently, so not sure how this fits in, but it should give you a good direction.

Here's the full build file which runs on Gradle 7.2 and uses the `circularimageview` arr off maven central as the test subject

```
plugins {
    id('java')
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    aar
    compileClasspath.extendsFrom aar
}

dependencies {
    aar('com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.3.0@aar')
}

tasks.register('moveFile', Copy) {
    from(zipTree(configurations.aar.singleFile)) {
        include "res/values/values.xml"
    }
    into project.layout.buildDirectory.dir('here')
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I cannot get the dependency to work though. I am getting the error:
Could not find method aar() for arguments 'com.project@aar' on object of  type DefaultDependencyHandler. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you including the aar in your build?

Comment: I am getting the aar from a nexus server like this: `

    maven {
      name 'Repo'
      url 'https://myrepo.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'
    } `
its working fine when I am defining classpaths in the dependencies. aar() will not work though

Comment: Ahhh, the `arr()` is a configuration I added for my example so we just had one file to consider (see the configurations block in the answer) I'll have a think how to do this otherwise. What do you have it as in the dependencies block? implementation?

Comment: hmm ok not exactly sure what you meant here. I am using classpath in the dependencies block. thanks again for your help!

Comment: Ok, I got to a more promising stage now. I can build everything like you are doing in your post. Now the problem is that the task is throwing the exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected configuration ':path-to-project-app:aar' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains more than one file.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show what you have now?  I'll take a look

Comment: Hey man! Thank you so much for taking the time. It worked for me now :) this was my first time touching gradle files, your answer helped big time

Comment: No worries!  Glad I could help 